# passing values to @Input() using syntax similar to `[class.name]`

Tags: angular

I have an `@Input()` that is typed as an object:

```
interface SomeDict {
  [key: string]: string
}
export class Component {
  @Input() someInput?: SomeDict;
}
```

I am able to pass in data using this syntax:

```html
<my-component [someInput]="{required: 'this field is required', min: 'must be greater than x'}">
```

But I would like to be able to do this (mainly because I can use string interpolation). It's a little different from the class syntax because it doesn't have the `[]`.

```html
<my-component someInput.required="this field is required" someInput.min="must be greater than {{ someMaxValue | currency:AUD}}">
```

I this possible?

Comment: I don’t think so. But you could just use 2 @Inputs right?

Comment: the input I'm trying to do is a dictionary (`{ [key: string]: string }`) so the component doesn't actually know what keys are available. I'll update the question to reflect that.